# Android maps.googleapis.com, issues retrieving JSON data

Tags: android, debugging, google-maps, httprequest, google-places-api

I'm using the following code to setup a mapview in android and display location marker which works well.

In addition I'm trying to use maps.googleapis.com with my api key to retrieve + display nearby XML nearby location data, either with Toast messages or in the debugger

I know I shouldn't be running HTTPrequest on the main thread, but for debugging purposes I'm just trying to confirm that I'm actually retrieving the required JSON data

(it works in the browser with "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=39.9165171,116.450872&radius=50&sensor=false&key=MYKEY") for example

I'm getting an unable to resolve host error in Logcat

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {

    MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;

    public MapView mapView;
    MapController mc;

    OverlayItem overlayitem;
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay;
    GeoPoint myLocationGeoPoint;
    String result = "nothing";

    private MockGpsProvider mMockGpsProviderTask = null;

    /* This method is called when use position will get changed */
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();  
        String googleAPIKey = "xxxxxxxxx"; 
        String searchRadius = "50";
        String baseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
        String lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        String lon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        String url = baseUrl + "location=" + lat + "," + lon + "&" +
               "radius=" + searchRadius + "&" + "sensor=false" +
               "&" + "key=" + googleAPIKey;
        Log.v(TAG,url);
        Toast.makeText(this, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);  

        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();  
    try {  
        result = httpclient.execute(request, handler); 
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); 

    Log.v(TAG,result);
    Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

never mind, figured it out by doing asyn task + json parsing

Comment: This is not an answer please be more descriptive as to what led you to a possible fix.Even i am facing the same issue.